Flipboard Create Magazine from Url - shows random description
We are currently attempting to create a magazine on Flipboard by adding blog urls from our WordPress website and using the "Add to magazine" feature. 
Link to our wordpress blog Site :
https://www.smorescience.com/roboticist-cynthia-sung
Problem: At the moment, the Flipoboard selects a random description rather than the real one when we add the blog link. (image below)
Screenshot
The image below displays the meta tag and the actual description
Screenshot
After carefully reviewing each generated SEO meta tag, it seems that they are all accurate. so need help figuring out what the problem is. must understand the process by which the flipboard retrieves the data from the provided website address.
